# if function not returning result as expected

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, boolean

I'm trying to add a 'Yes' in respective column if a certain string is found in a subject column: i.e. if 'visual' is found in the entry of the column Description, it should return a 'Yes' in the 'Visual Task' column.

It works as expected as shown in the first screenshot:

[image: test output]

However, when I try to use the if statement to populate the 'Visual Task' column, it does not work as expected.

[image: if statement output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**

(Note: *always* post **code** into the body of your Q in a block between backticks (```` ``` ````), don't use pictures).

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Description': ['VisUAL MINIMAL',
                        'REPRODUCIBLE VISUAL',
                        'visul EXAMPLE']}

df_datasetcritic_2 = pd.DataFrame(data)

# create boolean series
boolean = df_datasetcritic_2['Description'].str.contains('visual', regex=False, case=False)
```

Question: how to add column "Visual Task": 'Yes' if boolean == True, else '1'?

---

**Option 1**

- Use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```py
df_datasetcritic_2['Visual Task'] = np.where(boolean, 'Yes', '1')

df_datasetcritic_2

           Description Visual Task
0       VisUAL MINIMAL         Yes
1  REPRODUCIBLE VISUAL         Yes
2        visul EXAMPLE           1
```

**Option 2**

- Use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) (or [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html)):

```py
df_datasetcritic_2['Visual Task'] = boolean.map({True: 'Yes', False: '1'})

# same result
```

---

**Issue with OP's attempt**

Using an `if...else` statement here does not make sense:

1. You are using `is`, where you want to use `==`. `is` returns `True` if two variables point to the same object in memory. `==` checks for equality. Cf. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/132988/18470692).

```
boolean is True

# answer: `False`; so, your code executes:
# df_datasetcritic_2['Visual Task'] = '1'
```

2. Using the intended version (`==`) would have led to a very common error:

```py
if boolean == True:
    print('do stuff')
```

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

On the problem, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75788966/the-truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o). You *could* have used an `if...else` inside [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html). For example:

```py
df_datasetcritic_2['Visual Task'] = boolean.apply(lambda x: 'Yes' if x == True else '1')

# same result
```

Avoid this. It will be way slower than the above options, which are *vectorized*. See further [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/18470692).

Comment: thanks so much for your time in sharing the explanation. it was my first time posting here so wasn't aware of any formatting requirements. regardless, already learning a lot from what you've mentioned and all the links you're shared, thanks a bunch!